# Router connect same 2 ports?

Tags: networking, router, switch, local-area-network, internet

What it will happen if 'accidentally' i will connect 2 ports with the same utp cable? I'm asking here since i don't find anyware such a stupid and silly question but i'm curios about it, the router will damage or some internal parts? :) Or the switching part it will go mad? Or i don't know i'm just asking since my network knowledges are not so good.

```
router: port1 - utp to port2 , where port1 and port2 belongs to the same router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the router will be damaged.

Routers operate at a higher level of the network stack than switches do, so assuming that you're connecting 2 routed interfaces, you won't have a broadcast storm that is typical when two (non-STP) L2 interfaces are connected.

The worst that will happen is that (obviously) no traffic will be routed through those interfaces.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, as for switches what would happen, broadcast storming?

Comment: Do some research and find out! We don't spoon feed information here. This site is for professionals, and part of being a professional is being able to do your own research.